# Zoom design to fit every screen

Tags: zooming, scale

I am sure you have all come across this before but I just wondered if there were any new techniques out there.

I have been making a design for a client and they want everything 'above the fold' basically so that the pages fill the screen without scroll bars. I have explained that people look at web pages in browsers at different sizes and resolutions of different sizes etc etc, but this is what they want.

So I made a design that fit the viewport of Firefox at 1280 by 1024 which is the most common size.

Inevitable the client is now moaning that when they view this on their laptop screen 'the bottom gets cut off' so I change the design to fit 16x9, but then 'theres too much space at the bottom on the desktop now'...

I then stupidly showed them the ctrl+ zoom on Firefox, and they said, 'Thats exactly what I want, I dont want the layout or proportions on the site or text to change, I just want the whole thing to scale as it is to fill up the space'

I told them that I didn't think that was gonna happen, but I just thought I'd ask the community if they had any new answers to this unfortunately common request?

Comment: Perhaps responsive CSS3 media queries for device height? You can show different designs for different screen size. Set image heights, or layout changes accordingly. But that's a can of worms you're going to open....

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [liquid layout](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=14&gs_id=2b&xhr=t&q=liquid+layout+css&qe=bGlxdWlkIGxheW91dCA&qesig=YqJIkQmmEoR3BlcFcqTQpg&pkc=AFgZ2tkNsMVlCacvJX4XDoJS63P34F4LZr_xGy-y33sayYMbq2wvpw5FECW_CCCievd1Vu5hoaVl4LjzzWnB6i_0U4mqKJsruQ&pq=liquid%20layout&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=liquid+layout+&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=92e076a07569a785&biw=1372&bih=820)